# Navigate to Another Page With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new in MVC, when I click on a div with JavaScript, I want to go to the detail page that is relevant to that div. My JavaScript and controller code is as follows, and I get and error. Where do I make mistakes?

My JavaScript code:

```
<script>
$('div.ProjePartialGovde').click(function (el) {

    var projeid = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        method: "get",
        url: '@Url.Action("Detay", "Proje")',
        data: { ID: projeid }
    })
    .done(function (msg) {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Detay", "Proje")' + "projeID=" + projeid;
    })
});
```

And my controller.cs code:

```
public ActionResult Detay(int? ID)
{
    var prj = (TamYetki || OzelKullanici) ? (db.tbl_Proje.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ID == ID)) : (db.tbl_Proje.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ID == ID && d.BirimID == kul.BirimID));

    if (prj == null)
    {
        BilgiMesaji(Tur.Error, "No records found!");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(prj);
}
```

Edit: I changed my JavaScript code like this:

```
<script>
$('div.ProjePartialGovde').click(function (el) {

    var projeid = $(this).data('id');
    alert(projeid);
    (function(){
        Html.ActionLink("Detay", "Proje", new { ID: projeid });
    }) 
});
```

Comment: _and I get an error_ What error! (your creating a query string parameter named `projeID` but it needs to be `id` to match the parameter in your method)

Comment: And why are you making an ajax call that returns a view, but you never do anything with it. If you want to redirect, do not use ajax.

Comment: Redirect for another action requires form submit or anchor link - remember PRG pattern. AJAX calls intended to return action results at the same page, not redirecting to other page even you're using `window.location.href` in AJAX success part.

Comment: I get projectid correctly. but it is probably due to BirimID. I do not know JavaScript syntax very well. They gave me the code ready and I tried to change it.

Comment: If you want to "go to a detail page" then use `@Html.ActionLink("action", "controller", new { ID = item.id })` where `item` is variable for the loop you're using to create the rows and `id` is the projeid property.  (without the code that generates the rows, this is a guess)

Comment: Can you check my update please. I changed my code. I get an ID correctly but I can not go to the page. @freedomn-m

Comment: Can you check my edit sir? I changed my JavaScript code but I can not go to the page. @Stephen Muecke. I get the right id btw.

Comment: Ok - you missed the `@` part - `@Html.ActionLink` is a basic part of creating a razor page - it's not javascript, it's razor.  Put the `@` in and have a look at the source that is generated - you'll see `<a href='/Proje/Detay...`  can you think where this might be useful elsewhere in your razor page (.cshtml)

Comment: It just needs to be `$('div.ProjePartialGovde').click(function (el) { var projeid = $(this).data('id'); window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Detay", "Proje")' + '/' + projeid; });` - but that is a bad solution and you should not be redirecting when a `<div>` is clicked. Add a link(s) in your view - see the comments above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need ajax to redirect to a page.

Change it to:

```
$('div.ProjePartialGovde').click(function (el) {
    var projeid = $(this).data('id');
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Detay", "Proje")' + "?ID=" + projeid;
});
```

Comment: You don't need any javascript at all - change the div to an anchor.  (but I guess it depends on what that div is, which is not detailed).

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm not using any ajax and OP hasn't shared his HTML.

Comment: 'ajax' was a typo - meant javascript - and already added the comment that it depends on the html.